# Conditionally delete rows by ID in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df:

```
ID Score C  D 
1  2     x  y
1  nan   x  y
1  2     x  y
2  3     x  y
2  2     x  y
3  2     x  y
3  4     x  y
3  3     x  y
```

For each ID, like to remove rows where df.Score = 2 but only when there is a 3 or 4 present for that ID. I'd like to keep `nans`and `2` when the only score per ID = 2.

So I get:

```
ID Score C  D 
1  2     x  y
1  nan   x  y
1  2     x  y
2  3     x  y
3  4     x  y
3  3     x  y
```

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: why should `2  2     x  y` be deleted?

Comment: because ID 2 contains a 3! I want to keep the 2s only when there are no 3s or 4s for that ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df[~df.groupby('ID')['Score'].apply(lambda x:x.eq(2)&x.isin([3,4]).any())]
```

---

```
   ID  Score  C  D
0   1    2.0  x  y
1   1    NaN  x  y
2   1    2.0  x  y
3   2    3.0  x  y
6   3    4.0  x  y
7   3    3.0  x  y
```

Comment: Also this works: `df[df.groupby('ID')['Score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(2).eq(2).all()|x.ne(2))]`